# Add contextual information to exposed filter

Tags: views

My goal is to create a My Tasks list that displays ContentType:Tasks that are assigned to the user. However, this page should have an exposed filter that would allow the user to see tasks assigned to other users.

I've created the view and I created an exposed Filter Criteria that references Content:Assignee

With this setup I get a page where I can see the tasks assigned to any user depending on what I choose at the filter. I would like to setup the filter to choose the logged in user as a default value.

I'm aware that I can create a contextual filter that would allow me to list all items relating to the logged in user, but I don't see how I can allow the user to filter to another user.

Is there a way to choose the default value of the exposed filter to userid ?